# TabControl Styles and Using Different Images

Tags: wpf, styles, styling, tabitem

I want to be able to set different images for the different tabItems for the IsSelected = true and IsSelected = false. I have this much so far:

```
<TabControl Margin="60,10,96,18" TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="tabItemGeneralHeaderTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-3,0,0" Height="51" Width="41">
                    <Image Name="tabGeneralImg" Source="C:\Users\myName\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NetworkTools\NetworkTools\images\sidebar\homeUnselected.png" Width="41" Height="51"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="tabGeneralImg" Property="Source" Value="C:\Users\myName\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\NetworkTools\NetworkTools\images\sidebar\homeSelected.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Name="tabItemGeneral" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource tabItemGeneralHeaderTemplate}">
            <Grid>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tabItemGenera2" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource tabItemGeneralHeaderTemplate}">
            <Grid>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

I was wondering if you'd have to create separate styles for each tabItem or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it would be a `UserControl` with two images. Bind the visibility of one image to be the inverse of the visibility of the other image, and bind the other visibility to a boolean on the control, maybe called `ShowDisabled`. That way you simply have an instance of the 'TwinImage' with the correct normal and disabled images, and apply your style to flip the `ShowDisabled` and avoid the repetition.